# Freewall.js default on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i currently tried out freewall.js for layouting my content.I added a menu with captions that filter what content will be displayed e.g."everything" "photo" "print" and so on. But i noticed when launching my page it stacks the content boxes on top of each other with a little offset. it looks a little buggy when refreshing it, it rearranges the stack so it looks like a cardbox. BUT if you press "everything" all the content boxes will go in their proper place. so here is my question how do i change the js in that sense that it immediatly loads the "everything" page on pageload?

i add the link of the example that i took the inspiration from ( that page has the exact same problem)

http://kristynjanae.com/

regards

JS:

$(function() {
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");

```
var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
        var length = images.length;
        images.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
        images.find('img').on("load error", function() {
            -- length;
            if (!length) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    images.css({visibility: 'visible'});
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }, 505);
            }
});


wall.reset({
    selector: '.brick',
    animate: true,
    cellW: 320,
    cellH: 'auto',
    onResize: function() {
        wall.fitWidth(); 

    }



});

wall.filter(":not(.k1, .k2, .k3, .k4, .k5, .k6)");
$(".filter-label").click(function() {
    $(".filter-label").removeClass("active");
    var filter = $(this).addClass('active').data('filter');
    if (filter) {
        wall.filter(filter);
        wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 320,
        cellH: 'auto',
        onResize: function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
}
        });


    } else {
        wall.unFilter();
    }
});

wall.fitWidth();
```

});

CSS:

```
body {
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
    /*font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;*/
    font-size: 15px;

}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;

    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;


    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    transition: max-height 0.4s;

    }

    .black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

li{
    padding:7px;
}
/*nav ul{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10000;
}*/


/*----------------for Filter----------------*/
.free-wall {
    margin: 15px;   
}
.brick {
    width:300px;
}
.info {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight:500;
}
.brick img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /*display: block; */
}
.filter-items {

    /*padding: 15px 0px;
    padding-left:15px;*/
}
.filter-label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 2.5px 2.5px 0px;
    padding: 0px,10px,10px,5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#FFF;
}
.filter-label.active{

    color:white;
    background: black;

}

.photography:hover{
    background:#ffe6e6;
}
.everything:hover{
    background:#e6ffe8;
}
.webdesign:hover{
    background: #ffffd9;
}
.dreid:hover{
    background: #befff3;
}
.drawingsart:hover{
    background: #fcd2ff;
}
.projects:hover{
    background: #ffedc8;
}
.study:hover{
    background: #bcc9ff;
}
h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*position:fixed;
    z-index:10000;*/
}
h2{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin:0px 0px;
    /*position:fixed;
    z-index:10000;*/

}




a:active {
    color: #000;
}

a {`enter code here`
    color: #000;

}
```

Comment: The page you posted does not have the same problem for me as you describe. Try clearing your browser cache and/or make sure you are running the latest version of your browser. I checked in FireFox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: yes still it stacks the content like a cardbox just when pressing "home" or "everything" it layouts them into the freewall grid. how can i force it to do so on pageload? so i dont have the cardbox look?

Comment: Post your JS and CSS

Comment: the freewall.js i copied like it is in original.

Answer (score 0):

You must move this block code:

`var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
            var length = images.length;
            images.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
            images.find('img').on("load error", function() {
                -- length;
                if (!length) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        images.css({visibility: 'visible'});
                        wall.fitWidth();
                    }, 505);
                }
            });`

into this funciton:

```
        $(function() {
            var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
            ....
            ....
        });
```

Comment: hey minh thanks for the help some how it didnt work for me. i edited the js code in the post thats the current state. i am a bit new to the coding scene sry when i dont see clear ^^